# How do I write raw printer code to a windows printer share from ruby?

Tags: windows, ruby, printing, share

Using java, minus the exception handling, it is as simple as

```
FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("\\\\host\\share");
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(ostream);
printStream.print("HELLO PRINTER");
printStream.close();
ostream.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File.open("\\\\host\\share") do |f|
  f.print("HELLO PRINTER#{12.chr}")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

While I've never tried to print from Ruby, and while I don't have a Windows machine available to test on, it would seem to me that you don't want to be using the `File` class, but instead the `IO` class. You can see its documentation here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html. It looks like it actually has Windows specific options, so take a look and if it's not too helpful, let me know why.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I don't know why I was getting the error earlier but it is working fine now.